# Setting same frame width in matplotlib subplots with external colorbar element

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to produce two subplots that contain a lot of curves, so I defined a function that produces a colorbar, to avoid having a super long legend that is not readable.
This is the function to create the colorbar:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl, matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def colorbar (cmap, vmin, vmax, label, ax=None, **cbar_opts):
    
    norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, clip=False)
    cbar = plt.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap),
                        label=label, ax=ax, **cbar_opts)
    return cbar
```

I want to show just one colorbar, since its values are the same for the two plots. So, I place it only on the right of the second axis.
Here is the code.

```py
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({i: np.linspace(i*i, 10, 10) for i in range(50)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({i: np.linspace(2*i*i, 10, 10) for i in range(50)})

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(5,3))
df1.plot(ax=axs[0], legend=False, cmap='turbo')
df2.plot(ax=axs[1], legend=False, cmap='turbo')

colorbar(ax = axs[1], cmap='turbo', vmin=0, vmax=49, label='My title')

axs[1].set_title('I want this frame \n as large as \n the first one')

plt.tight_layout()
```

**My problem** is that now the two plots have different width, because the colorbar is considered in the measurement of the width of the second axis. How can I get the two frames to have the same width?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass to `colorbar` a list of axes, from which space is stolen in equal way.

[image]

```
import matplotlib as M
f, a = M.pyplot.subplots(1, 2)
#                                 ↓↓↓↓
f.colorbar(M.cm.ScalarMappable(), ax=a)
#                                 ↑↑↑↑
f.show()
```

If you want a "tight layout" you can specify `layout='constrained'` when instantiating the Figure and the Axes:

[image]

```
import matplotlib as M
f, a = M.pyplot.subplots(1, 2, layout='constrained')
f.colorbar(M.cm.ScalarMappable(), ax=a)
f.show()
```

---

`constrained` layout is, so to say, the next gen of tight layout and, as you can see, it's way smarter than its predecessor, that remains supported because of the tons of preexisting code that uses it.  I recommend that you use constrained layout in all the new code.

---

**ps** The syntax `layout='constrained'` is recent (Matplotlib 3.6?), previously one had to use the more verbose `constrained_layout=True`, that is still supported. If you want to use your code on an old installation, it's hence safer to use the second format.

Comment: This option seems to be not compatible with tight_layout, which I need to get a neat result when I add y labels and so on. Is there a way to use this feature while using tight_layout?

Comment: @gioarma You ask, I answer.

Comment: Thank you, the last edit solved everything!

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html

##### `fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), ax=ax)`

> `ax`: one or more parent
> axes from which space for a new colorbar axes will be stolen, if `cax` (axes into which the colorbar will be drawn)
> is None. This has no effect if `cax` is set.

By setting `ax=axs`, the space for the colorbar is stolen by the figure which it is applied to. However, `plt.tight_layout()` is not supported in this mode.

```
import matplotlib as mpl, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd, numpy as np


def colorbar(cmap, vmin, vmax, label, **cbar_opts):
    norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, clip=False)
    cbar = plt.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap),
                        label=label, ax=axs, **cbar_opts)
    return cbar


df1 = pd.DataFrame({i: np.linspace(i * i, 10, 10) for i in range(50)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({i: np.linspace(2 * i * i, 10, 10) for i in range(50)})

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
df1.plot(ax=axs[0], legend=False, cmap='turbo')
df2.plot(ax=axs[1], legend=False, cmap='turbo')

colorbar(cmap='turbo', vmin=0, vmax=49, label='My title')

axs[1].set_title('I want this frame \n as large as \n the first one')

# not compatible with tight_layout
# plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

#### Result:

[image]

Alternatively, you can create a third new `axs[2]` just for the colorbar. In this case, `plt.tight_layout()` is supported.

```
import matplotlib as mpl, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd, numpy as np


def colorbar(cmap, vmin, vmax, label, **cbar_opts):
    norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, clip=False)
    cbar = plt.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap),
                        label=label, **cbar_opts)
    return cbar


df1 = pd.DataFrame({i: np.linspace(i * i, 10, 10) for i in range(50)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({i: np.linspace(2 * i * i, 10, 10) for i in range(50)})

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10, 5))
df1.plot(ax=axs[0], legend=False, cmap='turbo')
df2.plot(ax=axs[1], legend=False, cmap='turbo')

colorbar(ax=axs[2], cmap='turbo', vmin=0, vmax=49, label='My title', cax=axs[2])  # make a third axs for colorbar

axs[2].set_aspect(0.5)  # adjust colorbar's ratio

axs[1].set_title('I want this frame \n as large as \n the first one')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this minimal example it does work to remove tight_layout. However, if I add a y label, the absence of `tight_layout` is a problem, because everything gets messy. Your second option is ok, but there is a large white space between the bar and the plots. Is there any way of keeping the tight layout option and at the same time avoiding the white space?

Comment: As gboffi solved the problem, and I think his way is much better, you should adopt his method. As for the second method, I think it can be done by adjusting the axes distance of the subfig2 and the colorbar.